# Wait for at least 1 element to contain exact text using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a bunch of sections that each have an `<h2>`. They render after receiving api responses, so the order that they render is non-deterministic. I want to check that some of the `<h2>` texts rendered correctly.

I tried this:

```js
cy.getTestid('container').get('h2')
  .contains(/^\s*Title\s*$/);
```

This test fails, even though the html contains `<h2>Title</h2>`. I think it's because another `<h2>` rendered first, so Cypress only checks if the other `<h2>` contains "Title". I want Cypress to wait until either an `<h2>` containing "Title" appears or it times out. How can I do this?

I'd prefer not manually getting the nth `<h2>` with `.eq()` because I might change the sections often. It's not important that the nth h2 contains "Title", I just need to check that there exists an `<h2>` containing "Title".

Answer (score 2):

You're right about `.contains(/^\s*Title\s*$/)` returning *only* the first element it finds with that text.

If `cy.getTestid('container')` is a way around the issue, it should be followed by `.find()` not `.get()` because `.get()` has scope of `<body>` unless explicitly changed by wrapping with `.within()`.

```js
cy.getTestid('container')
  .find('h2')
  .contains(/^\s*Title\s*$/)
```

or within

```js
cy.getTestid('container').within(($container) => {
  cy.get('h2').contains(/^\s*Title\s*$/)
  // or
  cy.contains('h2', /^\s*Title\s*$/)
})
```

or combining selectors

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="container"] h2')
  .contains(/^\s*Title\s*$/)

// or
cy.contains('[data-testid="container"] h2', /^\s*Title\s*$/)
```

or [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) in selector to overcome the limitation that `cy.contains()` returns only the first element (Note does not handle regex)

```js
cy.get('h2:contains("Title")`)
  .should('have.length.gt', 1)
```